# Professionally Indicate a Misspelling

Tags: orthography

I am writing a formal letter to a business colleague, and I know that I may have misspelled someone's first name. I do not have a way of checking if my assumed spelling is correct, but would like to at least acknowledge that I may have misspelled it.

I will often see such errors acknowledged like this:

> misspeeled (sp)
>
> misspeeled (sp?)

Is there a better way I can professionally acknowledge this possible error, since all other means of verifying its spelling have been exhausted?

Comment: This carries a slightly different connotation, but consider looking into the "Sic" notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic. It's not exactly the same, it might give you some ideas.

Comment: @vanderpn Great point, but this is within a different context.

Comment: In this context, I would be tempted just to add a postscript which acknowledges the potential error.

Comment: What @Will said. Or rather than a postscript, just write the whole sentence out in your parentheses: “Misspeeled (did I guess the spelling right there?)” would be a common way of hedging your attempt at spelling a name you’ve only heard spoken, for example.

Comment: If I don't know how something is spelled, then I write a (sp?) after it to acknowledge that I am uncertain of the spelling.  That's commonly understood.  It's important not only to not step on anyone's toes, but also so that a reader doesn't automatically assume that spelling is correct and attempts to verify the spelling independently before repeating it.  There isn't a more professional way to do it.  Remember, one of the mandates of professionalism is brevity.  If you can get the point across in just five characters, do it.

Comment: By the way, I've also seen people use (?sp).  The question mark always comes either before or after the "sp" inside the parentheses.  I put it after.  I think it coming beforehand comes from how professional copy editors do it.  At any rate, there's no need to belabor the point with a drawn out explanation when (sp?) or (?sp) gets the point across.

Comment: Are "(sp?)" & "(?sp)" American usage? I don't recall even seeing them in British usage, and think I would struggle to understand them if I hadn't read these comments.

Comment: @TrevorD I've never seen either used anywhere but on the Internet and in very informal communication. I've never seen a copy editor use either, American or otherwise.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

For me, the  *(sp?)* method has connotations of school homework. Although it's a little long-winded, if it's only to be used once in the letter I would prefer *(my apologies for any misspelling)*.

Answer (score -2):

I think it would be bad form to spell somebody's name incorrectly in a FORMAL business letter.  A formal letter carries the weight of the "extra effort" involved in drafting and providing the letter;  even acknowledging the error would ruin the "formality" of the letter.

I would avoid using the first name if I could.  Formal English gives you many, many ways to refer to somebody else without directly naming them, depending on the tone you are aiming for in the letter, spanning from "Sir" and "One" (If one would like to respond...), to simply using titles, to simply using pronouns.

If you cannot avoid using the first name, you really need to find it out through another means.  Find some clever way to find out the spelling.  Like the other answer said, call the front desk and ask.  Or, call the person themselves and ask in an informal context.  Check "About Us" pages online.  Facebook Profile?  LinkedIn Profile?  List of college alumni?  Dare I date myself... telephone directory?

Misspelling the recipient's name would be a breach of protocol, and pointing out the error would really read worse.  "Not only didn't I bother enough to learn how to spell your name, I didn't bother enough to care that I flagged it wrong."  Personally, I'd prefer somebody contact me and tell me they couldn't spell my name over them just guessing... but that's an opinion, I don't know your whole situation.

(If you really just want to spell it wrong, I'd try to make it look like a transcription error.  This was much easier in the typewriter and handwriting days, when you could fudge the word up with correction fluid or whatever.)

Comment: This answer does not answer the Q. and is merely offering an opinion.

Comment: This answers the question. The answer given is that there is no way to professionally indicate the possible misspelling. But please do not answer questions which should be closed, such as requests for writing advice.